# Transpose row data to one column based on unique column identifier in SQL

Tags: sql, mysqli

[image]

This is a sample table I created in Excel. My desired output is in cell E7.

I wanted a transpose of all my rows in one single column based on the ID in column A. I tried the same in Excel with a VBA, but did not work as my dataset was large. Is there a way I can do this in SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` :

```
SELECT id, col1 AS guid
FROM table t
UNION ALL
SELECT id, col2
FROM table t
UNION ALL
SELECT id, col3
FROM table t;
```